# How to assign ARGB format (e.g. 0xFFFF0000) value to Kotlin INT

Tags: android, kotlin, colors

In Android, RED (in Java) is defined as

```
@ColorInt public static final int RED         = 0xFFFF0000;
```

When we assign to the value as below (in Kotlin), all good.

```
val value: Int = Color.RED
```

However when I replace `Color.RED` with `0xFFFF0000;`

```
val value: Int = 0xFFFF0000
```

It will complaint `The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Int`. How could I workaround it that I could still write in the ARGB format?

**Note**

I know if we converted to signed Int as below, all works

```
val value: Int = -0x10000
```

But that will be too hard for me to recognize the color format value (i.e the FFFF0000 is referring to ARGB format).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val value: Int = 0xFFFF0000.toInt()
```

Refer to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4749.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Color.parseColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)):

```
val color: Int = Color.parseColor("FFFF0000")
```